# Telegram different between getUpdates and Webhooks

Tags: bots, telegram

id like to start using telegram bot, i already read the documentation, but still can't get my head, what's the difference between "getUpdates" and "webhooks" 
source: [telegram docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/)

can someone explain this in plain language
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between "getupdates" and "webhook" is just like the difference between pull and push!

Using "getupdates" you don't even need to have a sever! You call telegram server prodically by providing bot's token and it will send you new updates if there is any. It means that your bot is always busy calling telegram even if there is just a single update per your 1000 requests!!

Using "webhook", you first notify telegram about your server ip and listening port and your public key. Then telegram will call your sever whenever there is any update.

At last and not the least If you want your bot to be faster you should use webhook.

Answer (score 1):

Two method can get same content, but you can only use one of them at same time.

Webhook is dependent on HTTPS server, usually use in PHP.

If you haven't a web interface, better to choose getUpdates, which doesn't required HTTPS address to receive updates.

Comment: hmm so the only difference is webhook using https and getupdates not? i'm still not quite sure thats the only difference

Comment: @mistercat webhook is server-to-you, getUpdates is you request to server, both over HTTPS.

Comment: I most case, you should use getUpdates, it is easier to debug

Comment: There is no need to use https, even self signed ceretifcates are also accepted. And also https has nothing to do with php. You can develop your bot with any language out there which has api for telegram bot. (Nodejs, python, php, ...)